# Append value to multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, arrays

```
function append (array, value, dimension) {
  switch (dimension) {
    case 0:
      array.push( value );
      break;
    case 1:
      array[array.length-1].push( value );
      break;
    case 2:
      array[array.length-1][array[array.length-1].length-1].push( value );
      break;
    case 3:
      array[array.length-1][array[array.length-1].length-1][array[array[array.length-1].length-1].length-1].push( value );
      break;
  }
  return array;
}


append([0,1], 9, 0) // [0,1,9]
append([0,[1]], 9, 0) // [0,[1],9]
append([0,[1]], 9, 1) // [0,[1,9]]
append([1,[2,[3,[4]]]], 9, 3) // [1,[2,[3,[4,9]]]]
append([1,[2,[3],2,[4]]], 9, 2) // [1,[2,[3],2,[4,9]]]
```

This function works right only if dimension ≤ 3. Also, it is very ugly. What a proper way to do it?

**UPDATE:**
I know how to recursively *get* last element of array:

```
function get_last(array, dimension) {
  return dimension === 0 ? array[array.length-1] : get_last(array[array.length-1], dimension-1);
}
```

I need *append*.

Comment: Use a recursive function

Comment: The wanted behavior isn't really specified how to handle e.g. append([0,[1],[1]], 9, 1)

Comment: append([0,[1],[1]], 9, 1) // [0,[1],[1,9]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.append = function (aElem, aDim) {
  if (aDim > 0) {
    this[this.length - 1].append(aElem, aDim - 1);
  } else {
    this.push(aElem);
  }

  return this;
}
```

then

```
a = [0,[1,2]]; a.append(9, 0) // [0,[1,2],9]
a = [0,[1,2]]; a.append(9, 1) // [0,[1,2,9]]
a = [1,[2,[3,[4]]]]; a.append(9, 3) // [1,[2,[3,[4,9]]]]
...
```

(tested under rhino)

Answer (score 3):

A recursive algorithm will follow along these lines:

```
Base Case: Append to 0th dimension, Just do it.
Recursive Case: Append to nth dimension where n > 0, Append to n-1 dimension
```

Along the way you have to ensure that the values accepted by your function are sensible.

**UPDATE:**
You can try this:

```
 function append2(array, value, dimension){
    if(dimension == 0){
       array.push( value );
    }else{
       append(array[array.length-1], value, dimension - 1);
    }

    return array;
  }
```

This has not been exhaustively tested so be careful.

Comment: Pseudocode looks very simple, but I really don't know how to transform it to JS.

Answer (score 2):

Try this iterative algorithm:

```
function append(array, value, level) {
    var tmp = array;
    while (level > 0) {
        for (var i=tmp.length; i>=0; --i) {
            if (tmp[i] instanceof Array) {
                tmp = tmp[i];
                level--;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i < 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    tmp.push(value);
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding, you always append to the last and deepest array. If yes, there's no need to provide a dimension explicitly

```
lastArray = function(a) {
  var p = a[a.length - 1];
  return p.push ? lastArray(p) : a;
```

}

```
r = [1, 2, [3, [4, 5]]]
lastArray(r).push(9)
console.log(r) // [1, 2, [3, [4, 5, 9]]]
```

Comment: Nope. 

append([0,[1]], 9, 0) // [0,[1],9]
append([0,[1]], 9, 1) // [0,[1,9]]

Comment: Should be error. Gumbo's function return [0, [1, 2, 9], 3] and this is wrong.